# How to skip extra (more than one) colons in docker build --tag command?

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci

My script for build stage in pipeline is something like this:

```
...
build:
    stage: build
    script:
        - docker build --tag="http://192.168.134.131:8482/repository/dockerrepo":"$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME" .
...
```

I have to use URL with port for image name because I'm using local repository.

I've got this error on running this script:

> ERROR: invalid tag
> "http://192.168.134.131:8482/repository/dockerrepo:main": invalid
> reference format

and I guess it's because I've used **multiple colons** in the script, so docker can't recognize tag part correctly.

**How can I skip these extra colons in image name?**

Comment: Does it work if you drop the `http://`? (See [`docker image tag`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/image_tag/))

Comment: @DazWilkin It solved my problem. Tnx